# Filter Permission by IdentityReference

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am fetching some folder permissions, however, I only want permissiosn that are not "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" or "BUILTIN\Administrators"

My code is:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$perm = $acl.Access | where{$_.IdentityReference -notmatch  "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"}
Write-Output $perm
```

But its still showing "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" permission, how do I filter out that records I don't want?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:
`-notmatch` is using regular expressions and your string contains `\S` which will match any non-whitespace character (which is not what you want).

use `-notlike` instead of `-notmatch`:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$perm = $acl.Access | where{$_.IdentityReference -notlike "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"}
Write-Output $perm
```

To filter for multiple entries, I would use `-notin`:

```
$acl = Get-Acl $path
$perm = $acl.Access | where{$_.IdentityReference -notin @("BUILTIN\Administrators", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM")}
Write-Output $perm
```

Comment: its okay ;) you edited lots of mine ;) time to return the favor :)

Comment: ok how can I modify it so it matches multiple criteria, so -notlike "BUILTIN\Administrators" or "BUILTIN\Administrators"

Comment: what if I want to apply a function to it, say I want to apply function abc() to each IdentityReference in my $perm? is this possible? in one line

Comment: @SaadA Yes, of course. However - your question should be answerd so please consider to accepting the answer. If you have a new question, you should start a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41190427/powershell-apply-a-function-to-each-member-of-a-list