# Powershell apply a function to each member of a list

Tags: powershell

I have a list of permissions for a folder, I want to test if each IdentityReference in this list exist in another list consisting of IdentityReferences, if it matches do nothing, else remove permission for this IdentityReference.

Bare it mind, the above is only to describe what I am aiming to do, I already have a working code, but the problem is it is 10 lines, I want to do it all in minimum number of lines.

```
$perm = $acl.Access | select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | where {$_.IdentityReference -notin @("BUILTIN\Administrators", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM")}
```

Now I have to apply a user defined function to each IdentityReference in the $perm, is this possible to do all in one line?

Comment: `foreach ($a in $perm) {bla-bla}`

Comment: can you give us an example what you want to do with it? I mean it depends on the use case you have whether you can just pipe the result to it or you have to iterate over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$perm = $acl.Access | select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | where {$_.IdentityReference -notin @("BUILTIN\Administrators", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM")}
$perm | %{yourfunction $_.IdentityReference}
```

or on the same line

```
$acl.Access | select IdentityReference, FileSystemRights | where {$_.IdentityReference -notin @("BUILTIN\Administrators", "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM")} | %{yourfunction $_.IdentityReference}
```